# I got TradingView's Pine script errors

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am using this code in Pine Script but getting the "Mismatched input 'newStopLoss' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'" error.

How to fix that error with this function code?
Are there other errors in this code?
Full code:

```
//@version=5

//@author=Wanderingyoung

strategy("Buy and Sell Strategy", overlay=true)

// Variables

period = 10

movingAverage = ta.sma(close, period)

stopLoss = 0.5

profitTarget = 1.0

// Logic

buySignal = close > movingAverage

sellSignal = close < movingAverage

// Plot

plotshape(buySignal, "Buy", shape.labelup, location.belowbar, color=color.green, size=size.small, textcolor=color.white, transp=0)

plotshape(sellSignal, "Sell", shape.labeldown, location.abovebar, color=color.red, size=size.small, textcolor=color.white, transp=0)

// Comments

// This strategy enters long positions when a buy signal is generated and exits those positions when a sell signal is generated.

// It enters short positions when a sell signal is generated and exits those positions when a buy signal is generated.

// The signals are based on the comparison between the close price and the moving average over the specified period.

// A stop loss is used to limit losses, and a profit target is used to take profits.

// Functions

trailingStopLoss(stopLoss, price) =>

    newStopLoss = stopLoss + (price - stopLoss) * 0.2

    newStopLoss

takeProfit(profitTarget, price) =>

    newProfitTarget = profitTarget + (price - profitTarget) * 0.2

    newProfitTarget

positionSize(stopLoss, riskPercent) =>

    positionSize = strategy.equity * riskPercent / stopLoss

    positionSize

pyramiding(positionSize, maxPositions) =>

    pyramidingSize = positionSize / maxPositions

    pyramidingSize

// Logic

strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long, when = buySignal, qty = pyramiding(positionSize(stopLoss, 2), 4))

strategy.exit("Exit Buy", "Buy", when = sellSignal, stopLoss = trailingStopLoss(stopLoss, close), comment = "Stop Loss")

strategy.exit("Exit Sell", "Sell", when = buySignal, profitTarget = takeProfit(profitTarget, close), comment = "Profit Target")
```

How to fix that error with this function code?
Are there other errors in this code?

can you correct this code? ChatGpt generated this code

Answer (score 0):

`strategy.exit()` does not have any qrguments called `stopLoss` or `profitTarget`. You should be using `stop` and `limit` instead.

> ***limit (series int/float)*** An optional parameter. Profit target
> (requires a specific price). If it is specified, a limit order is
> placed to exit market position at the specified price (or better).
> Priority of the parameter 'limit' is higher than priority of the
> parameter 'profit' ('limit' is used instead of 'profit', if its value
> is not 'NaN'). The default value is 'NaN'.
>
> ***stop (series int/float)*** An optional parameter. Stop loss (requires a
> specific price). If it is specified, a stop order is placed to exit
> market position at the specified price (or worse). Priority of the
> parameter 'stop' is higher than priority of the parameter 'loss'
> ('stop' is used instead of 'loss', if its value is not 'NaN'). The
> default value is 'NaN'.